# What is the easiest way to know the namespace of a class in PHP?

Tags: php

Im wondering what is the easiest way to know the namespace of a class in PHP. For example I want to know the namespace of `RecursiveArrayIterator`.

Comment: The namespace of `RecursiveArrayIterator` is the global namespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$rc = new \ReflectionClass('CLASSPATH OR INSTANCE');
var_dump($rc->getNamespaceName());
```

Note: Empty string means global namespace